# Dynamic MVC multisect dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to created a dynamic multiselect dropdown. The below code is not working

```
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Solutions", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SolutionList, new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>(), "Value", "Text"), new { multiple = "true", @class = "form-control list-group-active-color", Style = "width:100% !important", onchange = "OnGetSolutionsChange(this)" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SolutionList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

var solutionOptions = "";

```
    jQuery(result).each(function () {
        solutionOptions += "<label><input type='checkbox' name='categories' value='" + this.Value + "'>" + this.Text + "</input></label>";          
    });       
    target.append(solutionOptions);
    target.multiselect('rebuild')
```

Comment: [Here i explain multiselect bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217787/dynamic-mvc-multisect-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
jQuery("#SolutionList").multiselect('destroy');
jQuery("#SolutionList").multiselect();

    jQuery(result).each(function () {
       $("#SolutionList").append('<option value="' + this.Value + '">' + this.Text + '</option>').multiselect('rebuild');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here below link i explain how to use bootstrap multi select

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202592/change-dropdown-list-to-checkbox-in-ajax-jquery-in-mvc/43205638#43205638)

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look